# How to create custom condition similar to "@ConditionalOnProperty" without using spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to create a custom condition using spring context.

- I am using `spring-context 5.3.13` (no spring-boot)
- I have a file named `config.yaml` under `src/main/resources`
- I have this `@PropertySource` custom configured: `@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config.yaml", factory = TypesafeAdapterPropertySourceFactory.class)`
- I am trying to get a property from inside a custom spring Condition:

```
public class MyConditionalOnProperty implements ConfigurationCondition {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        // just to test what property sources are present
        for(Iterator it = ((AbstractEnvironment) context.getEnvironment()).getPropertySources().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            PropertySource propertySource = (PropertySource) it.next();
            System.out.println(propertySource.getName());
            //prints only "systemProperties" and "systemEnvironment"
        }
        
        return context.getEnvironment().containsProperty("my.prop");
    }

    @Override
    public ConfigurationPhase getConfigurationPhase() {
        return ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN;
    }
}
```

- `my.prop` is present after the application context was loaded
- I have a bean annotated with the condition:

```
@Named
@Singleton
@Conditional(PropertyEnabledCondition.class)
public class MyTestBean {

}
```

I have also debugged and found that my custom property source are loaded only after this stage.

Is there a way to retrieve application properties in condition or recreate `@ConditionalOnProperty` without using `spring-boot` some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that my `@PropertySource` annotations were directly on my app's main configuring class but on a different configuration.
This means that they were processed only after the beans were registered.

So if you initiate your context like so:

```
var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
```

make sure you have your `@PropertySource` annotated on `SpringConfig.java` directly